# Is it possible to use if/else in prepareForSegue?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to populate a View Controller with some information (txtTitulo, txt1, img1), like this:

```
class EstruturaAnatTroncoViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var casca: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var cambio: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var aneis: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var cerne: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var raios: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var medula: UIButton!

var nameButton: String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let color = UIColor(red: 237, green: 236, blue: 238, alpha: 1)

    casca.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    casca.layer.borderWidth = 1
    casca.layer.borderColor = color.CGColor
    casca.setTitle("Casca", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    casca.titleLabel!.textAlignment = .Center
    casca.titleLabel!.textColor = color

    cambio.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    cambio.layer.borderWidth = 1
    cambio.layer.borderColor = color.CGColor
    cambio.setTitle("Câmbio", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    cambio.titleLabel!.textAlignment = .Center
    cambio.titleLabel!.textColor = color

    aneis.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    aneis.layer.borderWidth = 1
    aneis.layer.borderColor = color.CGColor
    aneis.setTitle("Anéis", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    aneis.titleLabel!.textAlignment = .Center
    aneis.titleLabel!.textColor = color

    cerne.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    cerne.layer.borderWidth = 1
    cerne.layer.borderColor = color.CGColor
    cerne.setTitle("Cerne e alburno", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    cerne.titleLabel!.textAlignment = .Center
    cerne.titleLabel!.textColor = color

    raios.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    raios.layer.borderWidth = 1
    raios.layer.borderColor = color.CGColor
    raios.setTitle("Raios", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    raios.titleLabel!.textAlignment = .Center
    raios.titleLabel!.textColor = color

    medula.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    medula.layer.borderWidth = 1
    medula.layer.borderColor = color.CGColor
    medula.setTitle("Medula", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    medula.titleLabel!.textAlignment = .Center
    medula.titleLabel!.textColor = color

}


@IBAction func sliderView(sender: AnyObject) {

    var storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    var vc: UINavigationController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SlideViewController") as! UINavigationController

    self.showViewController(vc, sender: self)

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if nameButton == "Casca" {

        var dtVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
        dtVC.txtTitulo = "Casca"
        dtVC.img1 = "casca.jpg"
        dtVC.txt1 = "A casca é constituída interiormente pelo floema, conjunto de tecidos vivos especializados para a condução da seiva elaborada, e exteriormente pelo córtex, periderme e ritidoma, tecidos que revestem o tronco."

    } else if nameButton == "Câmbio" {

        var dtVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
        dtVC.txtTitulo = "Câmbio"
        dtVC.img1 = "cambio.jpg"
        dtVC.txt1 = "O câmbio é um tecido meristemático, isto é, apto a gerar novos elementos celulares, constituído por uma camada de células situada entre o xilema e o floema, só sendo visível ao microscópio. Permanece ativo durante toda a vida do vegetal e é responsável pela formação dos tecidos secundários que constituem o xilema e a casca. A atividade cambiel é sensivelmente influenciada pelas condições climáticas."

    }


}

@IBAction func casca(sender: AnyObject) {

    nameButton = casca.titleLabel!.text

}
@IBAction func cambio(sender: AnyObject) {

    nameButton = cambio.titleLabel!.text

}
@IBAction func aneis(sender: AnyObject) {

    nameButton = aneis.titleLabel!.text

}
@IBAction func cerne(sender: AnyObject) {

    nameButton = cerne.titleLabel!.text

}
@IBAction func raios(sender: AnyObject) {

    nameButton = raios.titleLabel!.text

}
@IBAction func medula(sender: AnyObject) {

    nameButton = medula.titleLabel!.text
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    nameButton = nil

}

}
```

The IBAction func casca is working, but the others are not. I don't know why this is happening.
When I use other IBAction, nameButton changes its value, but in the prepareForSegue function nothing happens! What am I doing wrong? Thanks for helping.

P.S.: if you guys need more info about anything, let me know!

Comment: Actually I had forgotten to add self.performSegueWithIdentifier, silly mistake, I am sorry guys and thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to play with name of the button here. Instead make a segue for each and every button to the same destination view controller.

And coming to your question, the answer is "Yes, we can use if/else blocks in prepareForSegue method.

Change the method prepareForSegue as follows.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
    if (segue.identifier == "cascaButtonSegue")
    {
        var dtVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
        dtVC.txtTitulo = "Casca"
        dtVC.img1 = "casca.jpg"
        dtVC.txt1 = "A casca é constituída interiormente pelo floema, conjunto de tecidos vivos especializados para a condução da seiva elaborada, e exteriormente pelo córtex, periderme e ritidoma, tecidos que revestem o tronco."
    }
    else if (segue.identifier == "cambioButtonSegue")
    {
        var dtVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
        dtVC.txtTitulo = "cambio"
        dtVC.img1 = "cambio.jpg"
        dtVC.txt1 = "A cambio é constituída interiormente pelo floema, conjunto de tecidos vivos especializados para a condução da seiva elaborada, e exteriormente pelo córtex, periderme e ritidoma, tecidos que revestem o tronco."
    }
    else if (segue.identifier == "aneisButtonSegue")
    {
        var dtVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
        dtVC.txtTitulo = "aneis"
        dtVC.img1 = "aneis.jpg"
        dtVC.txt1 = "A cerne é constituída interiormente pelo floema, conjunto de tecidos vivos especializados para a condução da seiva elaborada, e exteriormente pelo córtex, periderme e ritidoma, tecidos que revestem o tronco."
    }
    else if (segue.identifier == "cerneButtonSegue")
    {
        var dtVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
        dtVC.txtTitulo = "cerne"
        dtVC.img1 = "cerne.jpg"
        dtVC.txt1 = "A cerne é constituída interiormente pelo floema, conjunto de tecidos vivos especializados para a condução da seiva elaborada, e exteriormente pelo córtex, periderme e ritidoma, tecidos que revestem o tronco."
    }
    else if (segue.identifier == "raiosButtonSegue")
    {
        var dtVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
        dtVC.txtTitulo = "raios"
        dtVC.img1 = "raios.jpg"
        dtVC.txt1 = "A raios é constituída interiormente pelo floema, conjunto de tecidos vivos especializados para a condução da seiva elaborada, e exteriormente pelo córtex, periderme e ritidoma, tecidos que revestem o tronco."
    }
    else if (segue.identifier == "medulaButtonSegue")
    {
        var dtVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
        dtVC.txtTitulo = "medula"
        dtVC.img1 = "medula.jpg"
        dtVC.txt1 = "A medula é constituída interiormente pelo floema, conjunto de tecidos vivos especializados para a condução da seiva elaborada, e exteriormente pelo córtex, periderme e ritidoma, tecidos que revestem o tronco."
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Change this,

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    nameButton = ""
}
```

Comment: Just make sure, your `nameButton` is getting set before `prepareForSegue` gets called.